# PhpStorm new line in HTML replace

Tags: search, replace, phpstorm, newline

For over a year I have been trying to do the simplest thing - do an HTLM/PHP search and replace in several files.

For exapmle if I want to replace

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
```

with

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<!--
TODO UNIVERSAL
Favicon
Page title
Active page
-->
```

I get

```
<!DOCTYPE html> <!--     TODO UNIVERSAL     Favicon     Page title     Active page   -->
```

I realize search and replace is probably considered old fashioned but I have found it an incredibly useful tool for 30 years.

I have scoured JetBrains web site with no avail and searched here and elsewhere.

I have tried /n, \n, \\n, \\n\\r etc etc and nothing seems to work.

I am sure I am being a dunce but could some other PhpStorm user please enlighten me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Search for:

```
\<\!DOCTYPE HTML\>
```

Replace with:

```
\<\!DOCTYPE html\>\n\<\!\-\-\nTODO UNIVERSAL\nFavicon\nPage title\nActive page\n\-\-\>
```

**Make sure that Regex option is checked**

[image]

*(here on screenshot you see the result of such replacement)*

---

**P.S.**
PhpStorm (and other IDEA-based IDEs) uses `\n` internally (while editing) for all line endings. And then, when saving, it uses detected/proper line ending.

Comment: Well that is sort of what I wanted but clunky (but HUGE thanks!) PhPS auto escapes the _search_ string in “Replace in path” (RIP) so can cut and paste that for the replace but seems crazy workflow. If I try  `\n` _inside_ a file it just echoes the characters “\n” and everything is on one line. So AFAICS to replace a chunk of code INSIDE a single file I can ONLY do this by using the “Replace in path” on the single file and to do multi file have to fudge. Workable I guess but crazy. It seems horribly inelegant. Wish JetBrains would sort this. Cannot understand how this is not a basic feature.

Comment: Well -- I have replaced it using normal/on-page Replace. Quite possible that you did not escaped all characters that needs escaping (since this one uses regex and final result might be affected by such characters).

Comment: My mistake did not tick regex. But to get the escaped version of a large chunk of code (I will be inserting about 40 lines) I have to go back to "find in path" to "code it up" which seems frankly daft. I don't fancy regexing 40 lines by hand as I have little expereience. I am just doing a quick dummy of a site and copy and replace of text would be a useful tool. Ah well I have a work around now. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

This can be achieved with simple and tiny application `geany`.

I don't know on which platform you are, but it's available on Ubuntu and Windows both.

1. You can open all files in whclich you want to search and replace.
2. Open replace dialog
3. Enter text in `find` and `replace` text box.
4. Here make sure one thing that you copy and paste "replace" text with new line character from a file opened in geany. New line character will be converted to some non readable character, but don't worry just replace it will be as new line after replace.