# PhpStorm 2016.2 find and replace multiline text

Tags: php, phpstorm

In PhpStorm 2016.2 I have a new project that has been inherited and [badly] needs updating.

There are many pages each with opening line like so (*example*):

```
<?
include ("/inc/db.php");
```

I need to replace this line with several lines such as:

```
<?php
include "siteheader.php";
require "class.myclass.inc.php";
$dataBase = new DbObj();
```

I have previously simply copy and pasted multiline code into the PhpStorm search/replace function and that's (usually but not always) returned the correct changes, although they're all squished into single lines, making them harder to read (`EOL` characters are removed).

- In this instance am looking specifically at the *"replace in path"* function as I need to apply this change to many pages.

I have [Read the manual](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/phpstorm/2016.2/find-and-replace-in-path.html) but can see no option for this. I think I could possibly use a Regular Expression but this would not be ideal (escapings etc.).

I have also looked but not found a suitable plugin from the [PhpStorm Plugin Repository](http://plugins.jetbrains.com/?phpStorm).

> **Is there a way of searching *and/or* replacing multiline text in path in PhpStorm 2016.2?**

Cheers

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is no *easy to use* multi-line search or replace across multiple files (`Find/Replace in Path` functionality) unfortunately.

Right now you have to use Regex option for that -- that's the only option that works.

Watch these tickets (star/vote/comment) to get notified on any progress in this regard.

- https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-69435
- https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-61925
- https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-145720

---

Manually making regex-compatible text can be quite problematic .. therefore you might use this few-steps trick:

1. Type your new text in one file to start with
2. Select such text and invoke `Replace in Path...` dialog -- *with Regex option pre-selected it should automatically escape your selection to be regex-compatible*
3. Copy that already-escaped text somewhere (just Clipboard should be enough)
4. Close dialog and go back to original file
5. Select text you want to replace and invoke `Replace in Path...` dialog -- it will have your initial text already filled in and regex compatible
6. Paste previously copied escaped text into Replace field
7. Execute find/replacement

---

On related note: https://stackoverflow.com/a/38672886/783119

Comment: Thanks for the info, LazyOne. I will follow these topics and hope it comes out in a future update :)

Comment: Your guide to regexing the text boxes works well. Cheers.

Answer (score 4):

You can do multiline Find&Replace with Regex option turned on

Find:

```
<\?\ninclude \("/inc/db\.php"\);
```

Replace:

```
<?php\ninclude "siteheader.php"; \nrequire "class.myclass.inc.php"; \n\$dataBase = new DbObj();
```

As you can see you need to do some additional work to escape some special characters and put `\n` instead of new lines, but it works. I've just checked.

P.S.
Indeed, it was possible to simply paste multiline text in previous versions, but it's not possible anymore. ;-(

Comment: Yeah, regex was the only way so far that I could see this working but I wanted to ask and see if there was a method that I'd missed. Thanks for the feedback

Comment: There is also `Edit/Find/Replace Structurally...` option that may be interesting but it seems it doesn't handle any text abut only valid code. I found it impossible to use it to modify PHP open tag (from `<?` to `<?php`), but works fine to do multiline replace on whole project.

Comment: I can do the PHP tags separately to the code within. I will explore more of what Structural search/replace can offer. Thanks for the info, dragoste.

Answer (score 2):

Type <kbd>Alt+Enter</kbd> to add a new line in either the "search" or the "replace" field.

[image: search multiline in PhpStorm]

Answer (score 1):

On a Mac:
open the 'Find' or 'Replace' tool, click into the text area and press the following keys once for every new line you want to create:

⌘ + 'Shift' + 'Enter'

[image: screen grab of the multi-line search goodness]

Answer (score 0):

Besides the suggestions on how to use regex for multiline, in case you want to match two pieces of code with arbitrary lines in the middle, you can use `[\s\S]*` instead of `[\n.]*` (which doesn't have the expected result). Example:

```php
//you can match the $result-related code using `\$result([\s\S]*)while`

$result = DB::exec($query);
//blabla
//something else
while ($row = $result->fetch()) {
```

Answer (score 0):

`\s` works as expected to match all whitespaces and newlines.

In my case I wanted to find `switch ... case ... continue;` syntax, so `switch(\s|.)*continue` worked as expected